# Do we really need to run the Vacuuming in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. Previously we used the PostGreSQL 8.0.2. At that time we need the Vacuuming for the PostGreSQL. But now we used the SQL Server 2008 R2. Is this really needed for Vacuuming ? Or it is handled by the server itself?

Answer (score 3):

Most administrators deploy some combination of regular maintenance jobs. SQL Server has command to [REBUILD and REORGANIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx) an index. A good starting point is [Ola Hallengren's maintenance scripts](http://ola.hallengren.com/).